# transmit data to an angularjs controller

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, angularjs

In my view in want include a java script file witch contains an angular module and angular controller

```
 angular.module("Company", []).filter('newlines', function(text){ return text.replace(/&/g, '<br />&');})
                .controller("DemoController", function ($scope, $http) {  

          $scope.Company.Title = title // this title comme from the view
}
            );
```

The data source for the controller comes from the view, how can i transmit data from my view to the controller.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

**Updated answer**

If the data is in a model on your server, you'll want to load it via $http, ngResource, or restangular.

$http example (in your controller):

```
$http.get('/server/route/12345').success(function(data){ 
        $scope.Company.Title = data 
} )
```

This assumes that "/server/route/12345" is a route on your server that returns a JSON object that you want to set directly to Title.

Also, you must inject $http into the controller (which you're already doing in your example code).

.

**Previous answer**

In your html

```
<input ng-model="viewForm.text">
```

In your controller

```
$scope.Company.Title = $scope.viewForm.myText
```

Comment: I'm using $scope.Company.Title to fill data in the domme, the data is retrieved from the server (asp .net mvc), i mean my asp mvc model contains the data, if transmit the data tue angular js controller then if put it in the dom

Comment: the data retrieved directly from the server when the user request the server, not by using ajax,

Comment: In most AngularJS apps, the HTML and JS files (i.e. the angular files themselves) are served statically and serve as the template and logic respectively. You then go back to the server for content/data (as shown above). If the data is on your server, you either need to get it via ajax call (i.e. $http), or you need to dynamically rewrite the files when delivered from the server to include the data inline to the files. The former is the standard approach -- the latter would defeat many of the advantages of Angular, as you'd have to reload the entire page/pages every time the data changes.

Comment: but i don't want go to the server, the data is present in my page :   var myData = @Model.Company.Title // this asp mvc. now i want transmit this data to my angular controller $scope.Company.Title = myData.

Comment: It's present on which page -- your JavaScript page (the one in which you have the angular controller defined)? If you're already dynamically rewriting that file, just set it directly: $scope.Company.Title = @Model.Company.Title. Or, more likely $scope.Company.Title = "@Model.Company.Title" (to let JS know its a string). Of course, any dynamic rewriting of the JS file necessitates making sure it's not cached client side f the value can change on the server. As mentioned above, this is not a standard angular approach.